# Qt, particle system and additive blending

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, blending, particle-system

I’m creating a particle system using Qt and c++. I want to blend colours of the particles that overlap each other – adding the RGB values on top of each other, so colours would get brighter, something like this:
[image: Desired effect1]

My code looks like this:

```
In custom QGraphicsScene class:
    QPixmap* pixmap2 = new QPixmap("E:\\Qt_workspace\\1\\smoke5.png");
    pixmap2->setDevicePixelRatio(0.5);
    QPointF origin2 = {250, 100};
    QPainter pix2(pixmap2);
    pix2.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Plus);
    pix2.drawPixmap(origin2, *pixmap2);
    pix2.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing | QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform, true);
    particleSystem2 = new ParticleSystem(this, pixmap2, origin2);
    v_particleSystem.push_back(particleSystem2);
```

And i create particles in a loop:

```
void Level1::advance()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < v_particleSystem.size(); ++i) {
        v_particleSystem\[i\]->applyForce(gravity);
        QVector2D v = { (float)player->x(), (float)player->y() };
        repeller->update(v);
        v_particleSystem[i]->applyReppeler(repeller);
 
        v_particleSystem[i]->addParticle();
        v_particleSystem[i]->run();
    }
    update(sceneRect); ///so items dont leave any artifacts though works without it when 
using m_view->viewport()->repaint();
    m_view->viewport()->repaint();
```

And Particle class derives from QGraphicsPixmapItem

But im getting this result:
[image: Achieved effect]

Any idea how to achieve additive blending?

Comment: I don't know much about Qt, but if I'm not wrong I believe they have an OpenGL module. Maybe try re-creating this in OpenGL in a Qt OpenGL widget. Or use GLFW if you aren't using Qt for anything else. (As far as I know, it should be possible in versions 1.3+).

Comment: Maybe some blend mode set to ADD?